# get element position

Tags: javascript, html

how can i know that a specific  is on another specific   after dragging the first  and drop it 
I am using this code in the head of my document to enable drag and drop of my divs

```
var dragapproved=false
var z,x,y
function move(){
if (event.button==1&&dragapproved){
z.style.pixelLeft=temp1+event.clientX-x
z.style.pixelTop=temp2+event.clientY-y
return false
}
}
function drags()
{
if (!document.all)
return
if (event.srcElement.className=="drag")
{
dragapproved=true
z=event.srcElement
temp1=z.style.pixelLeft
temp2=z.style.pixelTop
x=event.clientX
y=event.clientY
document.onmousemove=move
}
}
document.onmousedown=drags
document.onmouseup=new Function('dragapproved=false')
```

Comment: Agree with other users. Specially because your level of js/dom knowledge looks limited. Your code does not look re-usable at all and has lots of browser compatibility problems. Don't think it's worth trying to use it. jquery is not your only option. Look at ext-core, prototype,...

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using a javascript library such as JQuery to help you with this sort of thing--a lot of these sorts of functions are built-in.

Answer (score 1):

hopes,

Kevin is right do not try to implement a dragable feature on your own.  [Jquery](http://jquery.com) and [Jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com) have already done this.

Answer (score 0):

Learn JQuery! You'll never regret it.

Look here for a demo of draggable object using JQuery library :
[link text](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable#demo)

Good luck!